# Porque é que em Portugal se escreve "género" e no Brasil "gênero"?

Tags: ortografia, pronúncia, diferenças-transatlânticas

Porque é que em Portugal se escreve "género" e no Brasil "gênero"?

Já vi mais palavras deste [género](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/g%C3%A9nero) e gostaria de saber o porquê desta diferença.

Comment: Se alguém se lembrar de mais alguma palavra comente.

Comment: Eu não sabia disto, seria um caso de pronuncia?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Corre(c:-)to!

Comment: Tem algumas palavras em espanhol que só varia a silaba tônica. Às vezes, fica muito esquisito quando faço a pronuncia errada. Dá pra notar a surpresa da outra pessoa. "Cleopatra", p.ex.

Comment: @brasofilo fica difícil perceber como você diz "Cleopatra". Não consigo imaginar outra forma, que não a minha, de falar.

Comment: @JorgeB., tinha que posto a forma fonética antes: aqui falam "Cleopátra", no Brasil é "Cléopatra" (ou será que é ao contrário:)

Comment: @brasofilo Ah agora entendi. Já consigui ver como dizem no Brasil.

Comment: No caso do meu exemplo, acabo de me informar, se chama Palavras Heterotônicas. Será que o caso de duas pronúncias também? . . . Che, eu deixaria a pergunta aberta por mais um tempo antes de aceitar uma resposta, acho que motiva mais que postem outras, but just my 2¢

Comment: @brasofilo tens razão, eu costumo fazer isso. Mas a resposta foi tão boa que me emocionei e pus como certa. De qualquer forma o visto dá para mudar, é só aparecer melhor ;)

Comment: @brasofilo e em Portugal dizemos... "Cli·ó·pa·tra". Curioso, eh? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É porque as palavras como aquelas têm **duas pronúncias** atuais, uma com vogal aberta em Portugal e outra com vogal fechada em (grande parte do) Brasil.

Do artigo de Wikipédia sobre o [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990):

> Surgem assim as duplas grafias em certas palavras nas vogais tónicas e e o que soam abertas em Portugal e nos países africanos, recebendo, por isso, acento agudo, mas que são de timbre fechado em grande parte do Brasil, grafando-se por conseguinte com acento circunflexo: *académico* e *acadêmico*, *cómodo* e *cômodo*, *efémero* e *efêmero*, *fenómeno* e *fenômeno*, *ónus* e *ônus*, *pónei* e *pônei*, *Vénus* e *Vênus*, *matiné* e *matinê*, *judo* e *judô*, etc. Os casos de dupla acentuação gráfica abrangem aproximadamente 1,27% do vocabulário geral da língua.

A teoria é que deverias escrever qualquer das duas formas, dependendo do que realmente dizes na tua fala normal.

Comment: Adorava poder ouvir a dizerem "gênero" para ver a diferença. Tens 2 erros "En teoria" e "actuales" que nem sei o que é.

Comment: Eu "metrô" consigo "ouvir" na minha cabeça, mas gênero é que não.

Comment: O artigo diz que "são de timbre fechado **em grande parte** do Brasil". Seria verdade que os brasileiros que pronunciam estas palavras de timbre fechado deveriam escreve-las com acento agudo?

Comment: @JorgeB. Sempre podes editá-lo tu mesmo, sabes: tudo o que escrevemos aqui é um esforço colaborativo, ou deve ser assim.  Suspeito que tinhas alguma idéia (e bastante boa) sobre o que eu deveria ter escrito.  :)

Comment: @tchrist esqueci-me que já tenho privilégio de editar.

Comment: @DanGetz Pois não sei disso, mas é uma pergunta muito boa. Talvez alguém aqui o sabe. Quando eles vão sempre mudando as regras, pode ser difícil manter-se a(c:-)tual.

Comment: @JorgeB. se ajudar clica no desenho do alto falante no campo de texto https://translate.google.com/#pt/en/g%C3%AAnero

Comment: @tchrist a última frase está um bocado estranha, não percebi o que quiseste dizer.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é igual gênero e género...

Comment: @JorgeB. “Deves escrever o que dizes.” Se tens um *e* fechado, escreve-lo dessa maneira, mas se tens um *e* aberto, escreve-lo assim.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sério, a pronuncia é igual? Então a resposta não está correta. Pensei que o **É** tivesse este som diferente de **Ê**, será que a pronuncia é afetada por serem "proparoxítonas", ou algo assim?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a pronuncia é igual no *translate*. Na realidade não sei. Não deturpes as minhas palavras ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Judô, por exemplo, eu consigo dizer em pt_BR e em pt_PT e é bem diferente.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não deturpei (eita!!!), é curiosidade, pode ser que o Translate do seu browser use a voz em "português europeu".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Também me parece que no google tradutor é *género* que é dito. Compara aqui com o [Forvo](http://pt.forvo.com/word/g%C3%AAnero/#pt): a mulher também diz *género* mas o homem diz *gênero*.

Comment: @JorgeB. Vê o meu comentário acima.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento se calhar porque o meu tem este link: https://translate.google.pt/ e o teu deve ser https://translate.google.com.br/

Answer (score 4):

Em Portugal, numa tentativa de unificar as grafias adotou-se a regra de que quando o timbre da vogal pré-nasal é variavel usa-se o acento agudo apenas para demarcar a silaba tonica (à semelhança do que acontece em também, convém, etc).

No Brasil optou-se por grafar com acento circunflexo as vogais pré-nasais.

Portanto tem-se quilómetro, termómetro, andrómeda, etc, em Portugal e quilômetro, termômetro, andrômeda, etc, no Brasil.

> Emprego do acento circunflexo nas vogais *a*, *e* e *o* tónicas dos vocábulos proparoxítonos, quando elas são seguidas de sílaba iniciada por consoante nasal e são invariavelmente fechadas na pronúncia de Portugal e do Brasil. (Exemplos: *câmara, pânico, fêmea, cômoro*.) Emprego do acento agudo em vez do circunflexo, quando não se dá essa invariabilidade de timbre. (Exemplos: *académico, edénico, anatómico, demónio*.) O mesmo se observará em relação aos paroxítonos que, precisando de acentuação gráfica, estejam em idênticas condições. (Exemplos: *Ámon, fémur, Vénus, abdómen, bónus*.)
>   **Observe-se que o acento agudo nos sobreditos casos de pronúncia não invariável serve apenas para indicar a tonicidade, e não o timbre.**

Fonte: [Acordo Ortografico de 1945](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=acordo&id=6-19&version=1945).

Comment: O que dizes acerca de Portugal está em contradição com o [Acordo Ortográfico 1990, Base XI, ponto 3](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990): "Levam acento agudo ou acento circunflexo as palavras proparoxítonas, reais ou aparentes, cujas vogais tónicas/tônicas grafadas *e* ou *o* estão em final de sílaba e são seguidas das consoantes nasais grafadas *m* ou *n*, conforme o seu timbre é, respetivamente, aberto ou fechado nas pronúncias cultas da língua." Portanto não é so para "demarcar a silaba tonica"; também assinala o timbre.

Comment: @Jacinto O AO45 dizia que naquela situação o acento agudo não indicava o timbre. Aparentemente o AO90 já não dá essa indicação de não haver marcação do timbre, mas parece que na pratica não alterou os acentos nessa situação, mantendo-se como ficaram definidos pelo AO45.

Comment: O AO45 era para ser aplicado em Portugal e no Brasil (mas o Brasil não o chegou a aplicar). Daí que para unificar as grafias de Portugal e Brasil se prescrevesse o circunflexo quando o timbre era **"invariavelmente fechad[o] na pronúncia de Portugal e do Brasil"**, mas o agudo quando houvesse divergência (aberto em Portugal mas não no Brasil). O AO90 simplesmente admite a dupla grafia neste último caso.