# Great Vowel Shift na língua portuguesa?

Tags: fonologia

Em português (tanto brasileiro quanto europeu), algumas letras possuem diferentes pronúncias. Por exemplo, "e" e "o", em sílabas finais átonas, são pronunciadas, na maioria dos dialetos, como [i] ou [ɨ] e [u] ou [ʊ], respectivamente. Com consoantes, isso também acontece: ***x*** pode ser pronunciado como [ʃ], [ks], [z] ou [s]. Isso é evidência de um fenômeno similar ao [“Great Vowel Shift”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift), que aconteceu na língua inglesa?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, "vowel shift" é algo que acontece a vogais, então as diferentes pronúncias de "x" com certeza não fazem parte de uma Great Vowel Shift.

Quanto à redução das vogais finais, não me parece que se enquadrem tampouco. A Great Vowel Shift foi uma mudança generalizada na pronúncia das vogais, tônicas inclusive, enquanto a redução das vogais finais átonas do português só atinge... bem, as vogais finais átonas. Assim, só são similares no sentido de que ambas são modificações na pronúncia das palavras, mas são muito diferentes em escopo e importância.

Comment: A única mudança notável em vogais tônicas foi que o português brasileiro combinou as abertas nasais com fechadas nasais (i.e., enquanto no português europeu há "-ón-" e "-ôn-", no brasileiro só há "-ôn-", o mesmo para a vogal "e"). Vide [essa pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/569/porque-%c3%a9-que-em-portugal-se-escreve-g%c3%a9nero-e-no-brasil-g%c3%aanero/4662#4662).

Comment: @Seninha - Isso não é só a grafia?

Comment: Não, a pronúncia também é diferente. Por exemplo, vénus e vênus têm a pronuncia da vogal tônica aberta em Portugal e fechada no Brasil.