# Por que se escreve “alguém” e não “alguêm”?

Tags: ortografia

Exceto com palavras estrangeiras (p.ex., *idem*, /ˈidɛm/) e vários portugueses que falam *sem* como /sɐ̃j̃/ (semelhante a *ãe* em *mãe*), sempre vejo falando *alguém*, *nem*, *outrem*, *garagem* com e fechado, mas muitas são grafadas com *é*, o qual geralmente se considera aberto, como em *légua* e *pérola*.

Então pergunto: por que se escreve *alguém* em vez de *alguêm*?

No Brasil, a palavra *sêmen*, por exemplo, se grafa com ê porque é fechado no Brasil, porquanto é nasal, então, grafar e nasal com *ê* não é algo proibido de acontecer; outrossim, há *têm*.

Comment: Boa pergunta. Especialmente no pt-br esse acento agudo numa vogal fechada parece estranho - embora existam outros exemplos, como "também". Questão relacionada ou duplicada: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/569/2764 .

Comment: Acho que em pt-PT a vogal é aberta.

Comment: @Centaurus, não sei hoje, exceto os portugueses que falam "ãe", mas, no século XIII, era fechada.

Comment: Oxítonas com sílaba tônica terminada em ditongo nasal -em ou -ens são acentuadas.https://www.todamateria.com.br/regras-de-acentuacao/

Comment: Boa pergunta, também percebi isso quando aprendi a escrever (há muito tempo). Considerei que era apenas uma exceção (por motivos históricos desconhecidos) e como, apesar de ilógico, era totalmente previsível, esse acento não incomodava tanto quanto outros tipos de exceção.

Answer (score 1):

É simples. Escreve-se “Também,Alguém…” porque em português europeu, pronuncia-se com a vogal aberta, logo, o acento é agudo. Já vi documentos históricos antigos onde, no Brasil, “tambêm” era escrito com acento circunflexo, justamente por ser o que articulamos. Há, entretanto, a possibilidade de tais vocábulos serem escritos assim para diferenciar alguns que têm diferenciação para a forma singular e plural. Exemplo: “Ele obtém” e “Eles obtêm”.

Há outros grupos de palavras onde ocorre praticamente o mesmo caso, porém esses são adaptados à região.
“Sinônimo, Atômico, Antônio (BR) e Sinónimo, Atómico e António (PT)”.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, se você pudesse adicionar uma referência ou link às fontes que você menciona, seria ótimo.

Comment: Isto não é verdade, em português europeu padrão _também_ rima com _mãe_. Em nenhuma região, que saiba, é pronunciado com o e fechado.

Comment: É sim, na verdade a pronúncia do português padrão é limitada ao falar de Lisboa. No norte principalmente o ditongo é como no Brasil.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, não há distinção fonológica entre *vogal nasal fechada* e *vogal nasal aberta*, logo a princípio não importaria se fosse "alguém" ou "alguêm". (Eu, pelo menos, pronuncio como [ẽ̞ɪ̯̃], um ditongo que inicia com um elemento intermediário entre aberto e fechado; a nasalização porém dá a aparência de que a vogal é fechada.)

(Há em dialetos europeus distinção fonológica entre vogais *não nasais* fechadas e abertas antes de consoantes *nasais*.)

Por que então escrever "amêndoa" e não "améndoa", mesmo que a vogal nasal (e não nasalizada!) tenha a mesma pronúncia que em "alguém"? Para tal decidi pesquisar nas reformas ortográficas históricas.

Em *Bases da Ortografia Portuguesa* (1885) [1], há as partes relevantes:

> 5.º *bis*. Todo vocábulo terminado em *a* ou *as*, *o* ou *os*, *e* ou *es*, proferido com acentuação noutra sílaba que não seja a penúltima, tem a acentuação marcada na escrita. São innúmeros os exemplos; [...]
>
> [...]
>
> 6.° *bis*. [...] Ex.: [...] *pénsil*, *pénseis*; [...]
>
> [...]
>
> *N.B.* Pelo princípio 5.º *bis* devemos escrever e escrevemos: *porém*, *ninguém*, *também*, *além*, etc.; deveríamos, todavia, usar da ortografia: *porẽe*, *ninguẽe*, *tambẽe*, etc. Deixámos êste ponto para o Congresso.

No Diário do Governo português de 1911-09-12, página 3847 (primeira coluna, sexto parágrafo) [2]:

> O ditongo *em*, quando predominante em polissílabos, receberá o acento circunflexo, com em *armazêm*, *armazêns*, *porêm* [...].

Já no Acordo Ortográfido de 1945 [3]:

> XX
>
> Emprego do acento circunflexo nas formas da terceira pessoa do plural *têm*, *vêm*, *contêm*, *convêm*, etc., gràficamente distintas das terceiras pessoas do singular corresponde — *tem*, *vem*, *contém*, *convém*, etc. Essas formas terão emprego exclusivo na escrita corrente, preterindo assim as flexões *tẽem*, *vẽem*, *contẽem*, *convẽem*, etc., que se consideram como dialectais.

Em suma:

- Antes uns propuseram usar "ém" em todos os casos, e outros propuseram usar "êm" em todos os casos.
- O Acordo de 1945 propôs o sistema como é atualmente, no qual "êm" (para a vogal nasal graficamente acentuada) é usado exceto no final das palavras, onde *ém* o substitui, a fim de que "êm" final seja usado unicamente para os verbos 3ª pl. *têm*, *vêm*, etc., que não são mais grafados com *e* duplo.
- Depois o Acordo de 1990 permitiu variantes *académico*/*acadêmico* (aqui as vogais são só no máximo nasalizadas, não fonologicamente nasais, e com efeito a distinção de timbre antes de *m* e *n* ocorre em dialetos europeus); não alterou a acentuação do *êm/ém* no final da palavra ou seguido de consoante.

Obs.: o Acordo de 1990 [4] escreve "Note-se que se as vogais *e* e *o*, assim como *a*, formam sílaba com as consoantes *m* ou *n*, o seu timbre é sempre fechado em qualquer pronúncia culta da língua, recebendo, por isso, acento circunflexo", faltando erroneamente a menção ao "ém" final.

[1]. https://purl.pt/437

[2]. https://files.dre.pt/gratuitos/1s/1911/09/21300.pdf.

(Ligações encontradas em https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforma_Ortogr%C3%A1fica_de_1911.)

[3]. https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_da_L%C3%ADngua_Portuguesa_(1945)/I

[4]. https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_da_L%C3%ADngua_Portuguesa_(1990)